# как здесь работает вложенный цикл?

Tags: java, циклы, for

как работает внутренний цикл?
за счёт чего "j" увеличивается, если в начале каждой итерации он должен равняться `int j = i+1`?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    System.out.println("I");
        
    for (int j = i+1; j < 3; j++){
        System.out.println("J");
```

Comment: Интересно что внешний цикл вас не смущает, хотя по такой логике он должен в начале  каждой итерации быть 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Присвоение переменной int j = i + 1 происходит только при старте цикла до завершения выполнения внутреннего цикла программа к этому пункту не возвращается.
Цикличны только проверка j < 3 и итерация j, а j = i + 1 - это первичная инициализация цикла

Answer (score 1):

1. `i = 0`
2. т.к. пост. инкремент `i` увеличется на еденицу при следуюющем обращении.
3. печетаем `"I"`
4. входим во внутрений цикл (**только после того, как внутренний цикл полностью отработает мы выйдем во внешний на следующию итерацию** `(i++)` )
5. `j = i+1` // j = 1
6. печатаем 2 раза "J" пока `j<3`  (прокрутились во внутренем цикле, после вышле во внешний)
7. `i++` // i = 1 . печетаем `"I"`
8. входим во внутрений цикл `j = i+1` // j = 2
9. печатаем 1 раз "J" пока `j<3`
10. `i++` // i = 2 . печетаем `"I"`
11. закончили .......
    как то так..... такие вещи надо в дебагере просматривать, там всё подробно расписано по каждой итерации